# MacBook Pro screen is black when turning on with these lines on the screen

Tags: macbook-pro

Whenever I turn on the screen it is completely black and has these lines. Nothing else happens as it stays that way. There are no cracks in the screen outside. I am a student technician that is trying to fix this MacBook pro which was sitting in a room for a long time. I do not know the exact reason why this happened. Is there a way for me to fix this without having to order new parts? The workplace does not want to fund the new part, so I am trying to save it how I can.
[image]

Comment: This *looks* like a cracked screen (the diagonal white line) and the red(ish...) lines in the lower right looks (for a lack of a better term) like a hardware issue of some sort. Could be the screen itself or the GPU or something in between. My bet would be at least replacing the screen, but if you have the necessary adapters/cables and a monitor you could see if it is *just* the screen itself or a CPU/GPU issue.

Comment: How much would it cost to replace this type of screen typically?

Comment: That is a question for your friendly neighborhood search engine ;-)

Comment: you could use TV via HDMI